# Access: "too few parameters" only when run from .NET

Tags: .net, ms-access, odbc

I'm using the standard Microsoft ODBC driver to query an MDB from a .NET environment.

I'm facing the error:

```
ERROR [07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 2.
```

when running the following query:

```
SELECT [SP_TST].[PRJ_ID] AS [PROJECT_ID], [SP_TST].[SP_ID] AS [PC_ID], 
       [SP_TST_STD_INT].[STD_ID] AS [INT_PRES_STD_ID],
       [SP_TST_STD_EXT].[STD_ID] AS [EXT_PRES_STD_ID]
FROM ([SP_TST]
  LEFT JOIN
            (SELECT [SP_TST_STD].[PRJ_ID], [SP_TST_STD].[SP_ID], [SP_TST_STD].[STD_ID]
             FROM [SP_TST_STD]
             WHERE [SP_TST_STD].[TYPE_CODE] = "I") [SP_TST_STD_INT]
  ON ([SP_TST].[PRJ_ID] = [SP_TST_STD_INT].[PRJ_ID]) AND
     ([SP_TST].[SP_ID] = [SP_TST_STD_INT].[SP_ID])
) LEFT JOIN
            (SELECT [SP_TST_STD].[PRJ_ID], [SP_TST_STD].[SP_ID], [SP_TST_STD].[STD_ID]
             FROM [SP_TST_STD]
             WHERE [SP_TST_STD].[TYPE_CODE] = "E") [SP_TST_STD_EXT]
  ON ([SP_TST].[PRJ_ID] = [SP_TST_STD_EXT].[PRJ_ID]) AND
     ([SP_TST].[SP_ID] = [SP_TST_STD_EXT].[SP_ID])
```

but the query **works fine** when run in the Access environment.

MS doc states that `Prompting for query parameters is a functionality of the Microsoft Access user interface. However, the Microsoft Access ODBC driver doesn't have this capability; therefore, it generates an error message.`

But my query doesn't prompt for any parameter!

Any idea on how to solve this without heavily changing the query?

---

**EDIT**
Found that I needed to replace "E" with 'E' (and "I" with 'I') but it seems to retrieve different data.
Out for lunch, more updates later on.

---

**EDIT 2**
The solution was exactly to replace "E" with 'E' (and "I" with 'I').
Difference in retrieved data was because I was querying different MDBs, my bad! :)

---

Actually, the **new question** could be, why it works in Access environment?
Are quotes and double-quotes interchangeable in that environment?

Comment: You may close the question, if you have found the answer.

Comment: Though same connected Jet/ACE SQL engine, the AccessUI extends its SQL syntax with VBA functionality unlike ODBC/OLEDB. Hence, double quotes (the identifier of string types) are allowed in former and not latter. But it is always advised to use single quotes, universal in the SQL world.

Comment: @Parfait please write that comment as an answer so I can accept it

Comment: Actually I am eating my words on the double quotes. I just made several ODBC connections to .accdb files and successfully used double quotes. Please show your ODBC connection. Are you using ADO/DAO or Drivers?